# JQuery Ajax POST request in Symfony 4 profiler

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony4

It took me a while to figure out how to get data in Symfony 4 via a JQuery Ajax POST request. I will put the code that might help someone but it raises 2 questions that I cannot find answer for yet. Here is the code:

Javascript:

```
function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'response2',
        method: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "name": "John", "time": "2pm" }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

PHP (in Symfony Controller)

```
    /**
     * @Route("/response2", name="test_response2")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function response2 (Request $request) : Response
    {
        $data1 = $request->getContent();
        $data2 = json_decode($data1);

        return $this->json(['data1' => $data1, 'data2' => $data2, 'data3' => $data2->name]);
   
    }
```

and the result is as expected and all works fine

```
{data1: "{"name":"John","time":"2pm"}", data2: {name: "John", time: "2pm"}, data3: "John"}
```

However, I still do not understand something. If I do a very simple Ajax request for example like this:

```
function sendData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'response2',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { "name": "John", "time": "2pm" },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Even if it is a POST request, I have noticed in the Symfony profiler that the data are not shown in a "POST parameters" section as I was expected but in the "Request Content" section as Raw data.

Also I found that the header contained 2 references to the type `Content-Type : Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8` and `Content-Types: application/json; charset=utf-8`. I was not able to find any information about Content-Type**S**

So my questions are:

1. why and how ajax data are detected as raw data in Symfony and not as POST data?
2. what is the means Content-Type**S**, in what is it different than Content-Type?

Thanks in advance

Comment: jQuery does not convert objects to json strings, instead it converts them to param strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the doc that I have misinterpreted...

> When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the object's key/value pairs unless the processData option is set to false.
> [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Therefore even if the request is a POST request, the data are not know as regular POST parameters by the Symfony profiler, so it cannot find it in the request to show it in the  "POST parameters"section and display it in the "Request Content" section instead.